# GetIpErrorString - как получить локализованные строки?

Tags: windows, winapi, сеть, ping, icmp

Есть функция [`GetIpErrorString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa365951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Эта функция возвращает строки на английском. Например, "Request timed out.".

Как можно получить эти строки в текущей локали как это делает `ping.exe` (например, "Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если посмотреть внутрь операционной системы (Windows 7), то мы увидим, что библиотека `Iphlpapi.dll`, (`%SYSTEM_ROOT%\System32\Iphlpapi.dll`) экспортирующая эту функцию, имеет MUI-компонент `Iphlpapi.dll.mui`. Но этот MUI-компонент существует только для английской локали (`%SYSTEM_ROOT%\System32\en-US\Iphlpapi.dll.mui`). Если заглянуть в бинарные коды этого компонента, то мы увидим в ней интересующие нас строки. То есть библиотека должна брать ресурсы из `.mui`, но ввиду отсутствия выдаёт только английский вариант.

Получается, что у нас три варианта:

- подождать, пока M$ переведёт сообщения;
- самим написать `ru-RU\Iphlpapi.dll.mui`;
- перевести нужные строки в своём приложении.

Comment: Да, похоже все так и есть.
У ping.exe есть файл c:\Windows\System32\ru-RU\ping.exe.mui.
И там как раз фигурируют все русские строки.